# c++ - Multiple conditions in for loop getting incorrect result

Tags: c++

Given an array `A = [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]` I am populating another array `B` of same length such that `B[i]` is longest increasing sub sequence containing `A[i]` of subarray `A[0,i]` (Please refer Longest Increasing Subsequence : https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/ )

For this I am using following loop

```
for(int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) { 
    int curr_lis = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (A[j] < A[i])
            curr_lis = max(curr_lis, B[j] + 1); 
    
    B[i] = curr_lis;
}
```

This logic correctly populates array B = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 1]

But if I try to merge inner condition with the for-loop condition i.e. `(j < i) && (a[j] < a[i])` as shown below

```
for(int i = 1; i < A.size(); i++) { 
    int curr_lis = 1;
    for(int j = 0; (j < i) && (A[j] < A[i]); j++)
        curr_lis = max(curr_lis, B[j] + 1); 
    
    B[i] = curr_lis;
}
```

then the array B gets incorrectly populated to `B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1]`

I think I am doing something silly in merging the conditions in for-loop, can someone please help to understand the issue ?

Comment: The first version of the code executes the inner loop `i` times. The second one does not always do that.

Comment: When you move the condition into the loop, the loop would exit early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first example will work for each `j` value and find the maximum value. Second will stop the first time you hit `A[j] < A[i]`. So what if you have situation like `A[i] = 5` and `A[j] = 5`, but down the road `A[j+1] = 6`, `A[j+2] = 7` ... `A[j+100]=1000`. Your second loop will say I found maximum its `5`, go on and increment `i`. No A[i] = 6, but `j` will not go to `6` because of the clause `j < i`.

Comment: Your statement "Second will stop the first time you hit A[j] < A[i]" has solved the issue - Thanks.

Comment: By the way `j <= i` gave wrong-answer.  Thank you for your help.